# mplayer error: "Cannot find codec for audio format 0x55"

Tags: codecs, mplayer, streaming

I'm running:

- Lubuntu 10.10
- MPlayer 2:1.0~rc4~try1.dsfg1-1ubuntu1+medibuntu1
- w32codecs 1:20110131-0.1medibuntu3

While trying to play [a streaming rtsp clip](http://rtsp://rs2.SichosInEnglish.org:554/sie/heritage/01.mp3) with mplayer, I get an error message saying: `Cannot find codec for audio format 0x55.`

According to [here](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/win32-codec-howto.txt), audio format 0x55 is "MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3)", and should be supported by `l3codeca.acm`. I do have l3codeca.acm in `/usr/lib/codecs`. However, when mplayer tries to load this codec, it says (see full log below):

```
Opening audio decoder: [acm] Win32/ACM decoders
Loading codec DLL: 'l3codeca.acm'
Loaded DLL driver l3codeca.acm at 212d000
ACM_Decoder: Unappropriate audio format
Could not load/initialize Win32/ACM audio codec (missing DLL file?).
```

It looks like [this guy](http://pastebin.com/ViahYEx7) has the same issue, but he is playing a local file.

According to [mplayer's Codec Status Table](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/codecs-status.html#ac), this codec "conflicts with security kernel patches", but I'm not sure what that means.

Any ideas? I don't specifically need this to work in mplayer, I just want to be able to play it. However, vlc and openRTMP didn't work for me either (although I may not have been using openRTMP correctly).

Here's all the information mplayer spits out:

```
$ mplayer  rtsp://rs2.SichosInEnglish.org:554/sie/heritage/01.mp3
MPlayer 1.0rc4-4.4.5 (C) 2000-2010 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.
```

Playing rtsp://rs2.SichosInEnglish.org:554/sie/heritage/01.mp3.
Resolving rs2.SichosInEnglish.org for AF_INET6...
Couldn't resolve name for AF_INET6: rs2.SichosInEnglish.org
Resolving rs2.SichosInEnglish.org for AF_INET...
Connecting to server rs2.SichosInEnglish.org[75.99.96.252]: 554...
rtsp_session: session can not be established.
STREAM_LIVE555, URL: rtsp://rs2.SichosInEnglish.org:554/sie/heritage/01.mp3
Stream not seekable!
 file format detected.
Initiated "audio/X-MP3-DRAFT-00" RTP subsession on port 36274

==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [mp3lib] MPEG layer-2, layer-3
ADecoder init failed :(
ADecoder init failed :(
Requested audio codec family [mpg123] (afm=mpg123) not available.
Enable it at compilation.
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
Cannot find codec 'mp3float' in libavcodec...
ADecoder init failed :(
ADecoder init failed :(
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
Unknown/missing audio format -> no sound
ADecoder init failed :(
Requested audio codec family [mad] (afm=libmad) not available.
Enable it at compilation.
Opening audio decoder: [acm] Win32/ACM decoders
Loading codec DLL: 'l3codeca.acm'
Loaded DLL driver l3codeca.acm at 212d000
ACM_Decoder: Unappropriate audio format
Could not load/initialize Win32/ACM audio codec (missing DLL file?).
ADecoder preinit failed :(
ADecoder init failed :(
Opening audio decoder: [hwmpa] MPEG audio pass-through (fake decoder)
Cannot sync MPA frame: 0
ADecoder init failed :(
ADecoder init failed :(
Cannot find codec for audio format 0x55.
Audio: no sound
Video: no video

Exiting... (End of file)`

Comment: have a look here: http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/win32-codec-howto.txt for more info. Looks like a protected mp3.